# Fermi wavelength of graphene

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrons, graphene

Does anybody know the Fermi wavelength of graphene? I searched the Internet for a while without success. I found, by inspection with the Fourier transform of an S.T.M. image
$$
3.84e^{-10} \mathrm{m}.
$$
Is this value of the right order of magnitude?

Answer (score 1):

Your value is within the range of literature values.

[Hydrocarbon Lithography on Graphene Membranes](http://www.physics.berkeley.edu/research/zettl/pdf/343.APL.92.123110-Meyer.pdf) states "the Fermi wavelength of the electrons in graphene of 0.74 nm".  Many references cite this value.

[Another reference](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0508) says ~0.14nm.